# url rewrite error: www.example.com/example.com/index.php/webpage

Tags: .htaccess

A friend has a joomla website that has some weird entries in google. As an example, the entry for the marketing page looks like this:

**Marketing - Home**
   http://www.example.com/example.com/index.php/marketing

Google seems to add "- Home" to every page title and the weird link is probably the result of some kind of URL rewrite error.

How can we check if these are old google cache items or whether these problems are still present? And if the error is still there, how do we fix it?

Note that browsing the site everything seems to work just fine.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions at once - could you break this into multiple questions? Also, please provide the URL to your site so that we may examine it?

Comment: If you google "site:alcala.nl" you'll see what I mean.

Comment: key question is, how to get rid of the incorrect URLs in Google.